# How to create folder with intermediary folder with Applescript?

Tags: cocoa, applescript, directory

I think the question pretty explains what I'm intending to do.
I have seen some folder creation scripts on the Internet like this:

```
tell application "Finder"

    if not (exists folder new_foldername of this_folder) then
        make new folder at this_folder with properties {name:new_foldername}
    end if

end tell
```

But this script just create one new folder havving its parent folder. I would like something like this Cocoa NSFileManager method

```
- (BOOL)createDirectoryAtPath:(NSString *)path withIntermediateDirectories:(BOOL)createIntermediates attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes error:(NSError **)error
```

in which I pass a path as parameter and the folder is created within the intermediary directories.

thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution is probably to resort to the [mkdir](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/mkdir.1.html) shell command, i.e.:

```
do shell script "mkdir -p '/path/to/folder/to/create'"
```

Comment: Actually is what I'm using as workaround, but it still a workaround. Anyway, voted u up =)

Comment: That really is the easiest solution. A pure Applescript version would require parsing a given path, building it folder by folder until everything is sorted and created. For Applescript, that's a lot of code. `mkdir` is one line and it works.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'm afraid this is the right solution, so. Thanks for your help, buddies.